# Diacritic normalization in excel formula, without vba

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, diacritics, excel-2019

How to replace diacritics (accented characters) with corresponding alphabetical character with regular formula: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"é","e")`, without VBA, for large range of uppercase and lowercase diacritics like this:

*áàȧäǎāãåąⱥấầắằǡǻǟẫẵảȁȃẩẳạḁậặăâ =a*

*ÁÀȦÄǍĀÃÅĄȺẤẦẮẰǠǺǞẪẴẢȀȂẨẲẠḀẬẶĂÂ = A*

*ḃƀɓḅḇ =b*

ḂɃƁḄḆ = B

*ćċĉčçȼḉƈɔ =c*

*ĆĊĈČÇȻḈƇƆ = C*

*ḋďḑđɗḍḓḏðɖ =d*

*ḊĎḐĐƊḌḒḎÐƉ =D*

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Excel 2019 (the version you are using) this is quite a stretch. I'd suggest something along the following lines:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(IF(EXACT(UPPER(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)),MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)),UPPER(MID(A2,SEARCH(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1),A1),1)),MID(A2,FIND(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1),A1),1)),MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)))
```

Understandig the limit of `SEARCH()` (255 chars) I opted to only include the lowercase variants and add the extra needed intelligence inside the formulae through functions like `IF()`, `EXACT()` and `UPPER()`. Again, this is an CSE-entered array formula.

---

EDIT: Without helper:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(IF(EXACT(UPPER(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)),MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)),UPPER(MID("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbcccccccccdddddddddd",SEARCH(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1),"áàȧäǎāãåąⱥấầắằǡǻǟẫẵảȁȃẩẳạḁậặăâḃƀɓḅḇćċĉčçȼḉƈɔḋďḑđɗḍḓḏðɖ"),1)),MID("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbcccccccccdddddddddd",FIND(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1),"áàȧäǎāãåąⱥấầắằǡǻǟẫẵảȁȃẩẳạḁậặăâḃƀɓḅḇćċĉčçȼḉƈɔḋďḑđɗḍḓḏðɖ"),1)),MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)))
```

---

EDIT2: With all lowercase diacritics:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(IF(EXACT(UPPER(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)),MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)),UPPER(MID(CONCATENATE("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbcccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffggggggggghhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjkkkkkkkklllllllllllll","mmmnnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooopppprrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvwwwwwwxxyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzz"),SEARCH(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1),CONCATENATE("áàȧäǎāãåąⱥấầắằǡǻǟẫẵảȁȃẩẳạḁậặăâḃƀɓḅḇćċĉčçȼḉƈɔḋďḑđɗḍḓḏðɖéèėêëěĕēẽęȩɇếềḗḕễḝẻȅȇểẹḙḛệéèêëḟƒǵġĝǧğḡģǥɠḣĥḧȟḩħḥḫⱨıíìïǐĭīĩįɨḯỉȉȋịḭíìïîȷĵǰḱǩķƙᶄḳḵⱪĺŀľɫⱡļƚłḷḽḻḹꝈ","ḿṁṃńǹṅňñņɲṇṋṉñŋóòȯôöǒŏōõǫőốồɵøṓṑṍȫỗṏǿȭǭỏȍȏơổọớờỡộởợóòôöõṕṗᵽƥʀŕṙřŗɍɽȑȓṛṟṝśṡŝšṥṧṣṩşṫťƭṭʈṱṯⱦţŧúùûüǔŭūũůųűʉǘǜṹṻủȕȗưụṳứừṷṵữửựúùûüṽṿẃẁẇŵẅẉẋẍýỳẏŷÿȳỹɏỷƴỵýźżẑžƶẓẕ")),1)),MID(CONCATENATE("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbcccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffggggggggghhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjjkkkkkkkklllllllllllll","mmmnnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooopppprrrrrrrrrrrrsssssssssttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvwwwwwwxxyyyyyyyyyyyyzzzzzzz"),FIND(MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1),CONCATENATE("áàȧäǎāãåąⱥấầắằǡǻǟẫẵảȁȃẩẳạḁậặăâḃƀɓḅḇćċĉčçȼḉƈɔḋďḑđɗḍḓḏðɖéèėêëěĕēẽęȩɇếềḗḕễḝẻȅȇểẹḙḛệéèêëḟƒǵġĝǧğḡģǥɠḣĥḧȟḩħḥḫⱨıíìïǐĭīĩįɨḯỉȉȋịḭíìïîȷĵǰḱǩķƙᶄḳḵⱪĺŀľɫⱡļƚłḷḽḻḹꝈ","ḿṁṃńǹṅňñņɲṇṋṉñŋóòȯôöǒŏōõǫőốồɵøṓṑṍȫỗṏǿȭǭỏȍȏơổọớờỡộởợóòôöõṕṗᵽƥʀŕṙřŗɍɽȑȓṛṟṝśṡŝšṥṧṣṩşṫťƭṭʈṱṯⱦţŧúùûüǔŭūũůųűʉǘǜṹṻủȕȗưụṳứừṷṵữửựúùûüṽṿẃẁẇŵẅẉẋẍýỳẏŷÿȳỹɏỷƴỵýźżẑžƶẓẕ")),1)),MID(B1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(B1))),1)))
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, exist a couple type of diacritics without case diference. For exemple "Ꝉ". So alphabetical output for this diacritic always will be lowercase and newer uppercase.

Comment: @losai, you can switch the logic around quite easily if you want

Comment: Of course :) Now I'm curious ho to build your formula works without matter of case. For exemple: ḂȧȻ result BAC or bac